# Формирование path c помощью os.path.join

Tags: python

Подскажите все ли корректно при формировании path c помощью os.path.join по получаю обратный слеш перед именем файла. Как сделать что бы путь был корректный виндовый.

```
 with os.scandir(dirname) as files:
            for file in files:
               if file.is_file():
                   print(os.path.join(dirname, file.name))
```

Результат:

```
C:/Users/Пользователь/Desktop/XXXXX\icon.ico
```

Comment: `os.path.join` не очень интеллектуальный. В [исходниках](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/ntpath.py#L107) я не вижу, чтобы он менял тип разделителя в изначальном пути. Попробуйте Path из pathlib, возможно с ним будет лучше работать. P.S. Да, pathlib при преобразовании в строку меняет разделитель: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA4ad.png

Comment: ну так виндовый и есть обратный слеш. Это у вас в dirname (который суть строка) как раз не виндовые слеши.

Comment: vitidev, спасибо за замечание, действительно получается слеши слева не "виндовые", я их получаю из dirname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите каталог с  исходными файлами"), может я как-то некорректно использую QFileDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо.

Как правильно заметил vitidev,  действительно получается слеши слева не "виндовые", я их получаю из

```
dirname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите каталог с исходными файлами")
```

добавил

```
dirname = QtCore.QDir.toNativeSeparators(dirname)
```

Теперь путь стал красивым:

```
C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\XXXXX\icon.ico
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы перешел на [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Тут сразу будет путь от директории:

```
from pathlib import Path

...

for file in Path(dirname).iterdir():
    if file.is_file():
        print(file)
```

Если нужно путь сложить, то это можно сделать через оператор `/`, типа:

```
file_name = '1.txt'
path = Path(dirname) / 'src' / file_name
```

А направление слэша (`/` или `\`) будет от текущей системы учитываться

Единственное то, что `file` будет не строкой, а [объектом](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths) со своими полями и методами, питоничьи функции из коробки (типа `open`, `os.path.*`, `shututil.*`) умеют с ним работать, но если нужно получить именно строку, то нужно в `str` оборачивать: `str(file)`

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно сделать так:

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.basename(filename))
```

Получаем текущую папку, затем берём название файла и соединяем в единый путь. Получать папку необязательно, главное корректно получить путь к ней, например: `os.path.normpath(path)`

Т.е. в вашем случае получится так:

```
dirname = os.path.normpath(dirname)
with os.scandir(dirname) as files:
        for file in files:
           if file.is_file():
               print(os.path.join(dirname, os.path.basename(file.name)))
```

И как уже отметили, можно действительно воспользоваться `Pathlib`.